# creating a nested array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to create a game using HTML and Javascript with Sublime. 
However I am trying to create a nested array with Javascript but then I run the code it doesn't work on the browser. The array "circles" should contain the "balls" (if you delete this line the game contains only one ball and it works).

This is the code of the game:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Canvas Tutorial</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = draw;

        x = 200;
        y = 150;
        r = 40;
        direction = 1;
        speedX = 1;
        speedY = 2;

        var circles = [{x:200,y:150,r:40,d:1,speedX=1,speedY=2},{x:200,y:150,r:40,d:1,speedX=1,speedY=2}];



        function bottomRight() {
            x += speedX;
            y += speedY;
        }

        function upLeft() {
            x -= speedX;
            y -= speedY;
        }

        function upRight() {
            x += speedX;
            y -= speedY;

        }

        function bottomLeft() {
            x -= speedX;
            y += speedY;
        }

        function draw() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");



            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,400,300);
            ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            ctx.fill();

            if((y > 300 - r) && direction ===1){
                direction = 2;
            } else if((x > 400 - r) && (direction===2)) {
                direction = 3;
            } else if ((y > 300 - r) && (direction===4)) {
                direction = 3;
            } else if ((y <= r) && direction === 3) {
                direction = 4;
            } else if ((x < r) && direction === 4){
                direction = 1;
            } else if ((y < r) && direction === 2) {
                direction = 1;
            }

            if (direction === 1) {
                bottomRight();
            } else if (direction === 2) {
                upRight();
            } else if (direction === 3) {
                upLeft();
            } else {
                bottomLeft();
            }

        }

        setInterval(draw, 10);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix the code?

Comment: If you call `draw` as an event listener for `window.onload`, then creating an interval outside of said listener is a bit counterproductive. Either use `window.addEventListener("load", function(){draw(); setInterval(draw, 10);});` or place `setTimeout(draw, 10);` inside `draw` and remove the interval.

Comment: I don't see how you use `circles` in your code. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You have error in your circles declaration - replace `equals` with `colons`:

```
var circles = [{x:200,y:150,r:40,d:1,speedX:1,speedY:2},{x:200,y:150,r:40,d:1,speedX:1,speedY:2}];
```

Comment: @MicheledellaMea, no problem upvote or accept if helped :)

Answer (score 0):

you don't use circles in your code. maybe you should create a

```
function Ball(ball) {
    this.x = ball.x;
    this.y = ball.y;
    ...
    this.speedY = ball.speedY;
}    
Ball.prototype.bottomRight = function() {
        this.x += speedX;
        this.y += speedY;
}
...
Ball.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {  
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ...
}
```

and use it in your draw function:

```
var circles = [
    new Ball({x:200, y:150, r:40, d:1, speedX:1, speedY:2}), 
    new Ball({x:200, y:150, r:40, d:1, speedX:1, speedY:2})
]; 

function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,400,300);
    cirlces.forEach(function(ball) { ball.draw(ctx); });
}    

setInterval(draw, 10);
```